# Adding shared generic functionality via an interface

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to have an interface `IMovable<T>` with one method `T Move(Vector v)`. The goal is to return an appropriately moved `T`.

```
public interface IMovable<T>
{
    T Move(Vector v);
}

public readonly record struct Foo : IMovable<Foo>
{
    public Foo Move(Vector v) => StaticMove(v);

    private static Foo StaticMove(Vector V) {/*Move logic*/}
}
```

This is working code, but how can I create a collection of `IMovable` things and ask all the items in the collection to `Move()`?  I thought maybe this:

```
public interface IMovable
{
   IMovable Move(Vector V);
}
```

But this isn't correct, because as demonstrated with generics, Calling `Move()` on `T` should be restrictedly-invariant and only able to return a `T`.

What should I do?

EDIT:

```
public interface IPrimitive
{
    public static List<IPrimitive> MoveThenScale(List<IPrimitive> items)
    {
        List<IPrimitive> returnlist = new();
        foreach (var i in items)
        {
            var iter = i;
            if (iter is IMovable imov) iter = imov.Move();
            if (iter is IScalable iscal) iter = iscal.Scale();
            //etc

            returnlist.Add(iter);

        }
        return returnlist;
    }


}

public interface IMovable : IPrimitive
{
    IMovable Move();
}

public interface IScalable : IPrimitive
{
    IScalable Scale();
}
```

Edit to provide a working code sample, which I think won't help my case much. I think an abstraction of my question is "I am trying to achieve type-safety at runtime when the type is unknown" which I think is breaking a few rules. Any thoughts?

Comment: "and ask all the items in the collection to Move()" So presumably you don't want the result of these `Move()` calls and just want their side effects?

Comment: Note that working with value types via interfaces leads to boxing and possibly losing all performance gains and also sometimes to some not expected effects.

Comment: @GuruStron Hence why I tried to make `IMovable<T>` generic...

Comment: @NWoodsman it will not help if you want to work with it as collection of interfaces (generic or not).

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce both generic and non-generic versions of `IMovable` interface (like `IEnumerable` does) and implement generic one and non-generic one using [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation):

```cs
public interface IMovable : IPrimitive
{
    IMovable Move(Vector V);
}

public interface IMovable<T> : IMovable where T : IMovable, IMovable<T> // I'm using curiously recurring template pattern here but that is not required here
{
    T Move(Vector v);
}

public readonly record struct Foo : IMovable<Foo>
{
    public Foo Move(Vector v) => StaticMove(v);
    
    IMovable IMovable.Move(Vector V) // explicit interface implementation
    {
        return Move(V); // note that this return will allocate possibly IMovable.Move should be void
    }
    
    private static Foo StaticMove(Vector V) {/*Move logic*/}
}
```

Comment: I get a caution that `T Move()` hides the inherited member `IMovable.Move()`. Were you intentionally hiding it?

Comment: @NWoodsman you can add `new` modifier to the generic method. And still note that unless you are planning to have collection of the same `T`'s there would be performance hit due to boxing which can lead to worse performance (though you should check this in context of your app and runtime) if using `struct`'s compared to `class`es.

Comment: I know this might be outside the scope of a comment, but I want to heed your warning. Lets say I represent the same domain object via both a struct and a wrapper class. I can enter a method and perform complex math with lots of single-use stack allocation. Then I assign the struct to a wrapper class to leave the method, so that only the final allocation is on the heap. Is this sensible, having the same object dual-represented one for speed, one for "ease" of passing around?

Comment: @NWoodsman (Note, coming from assumption that the code you are writing is that critical to performance) as always the most important thing is to measure, measure and one more time - measure (if not yet already - https://benchmarkdotnet.org/ to the "rescue"). Without seeing the code it is very hard to argue what does make sense and what does not. The approach with wrapper may be can do the trick in some cases. Or maybe you can write your own collection which will be aggregation of different collections of `T`'s(though I'm a little bit sick right now and can generate some strange suggestions=).